# Output from file using function

Tags: c++, visual-studio

the title says it all

This is my code:
I have a class called House, where i define the values.

```
class HOUSE
{
public:
    int id;
    string 1;
    string 2;
    string 3;
    int an;


};

template<class Type>
class table
{
public:

    vector<Type> V;
    //double inceput;
    //double sfirsit;
    //int comparatii;
    //int interschimbari;   
public:
    table();
    void print();
    void liniar();
};

template<class Type>
table<Type>::table()
{
    ifstream file("file.txt");
    ifstream file1("file1.txt");

    if (file.fail() || file1.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Eroare la deschiderea fisierului!" << endl;
        _getch();
        exit(1);
    }

    HOUSE* value = new HOUSE;

while (!file.eof() || file1.fail())
{
    file >> value->id;
    file >> value->tara;
    file >> value->brand;
    file >> value->culoare;
    file >> value->an;

    this->V.push_back(*value);
}


file.close();
```

}

The print function for the values

```
template<class Type>
void table<Type>::print()
{

    cout << endl << setw(50) << "AFISAREA DATELOR" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << "Id" << setw(15) << "1" << setw(20) << "2" << setw(17) << "3" << setw(20) << "an" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->V.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << this->V.at(i).id << setw(15)
            << this->V.at(i).1<< setw(17)
            << this->V.at(i).2<< setw(17)
            << this->V.at(i).3<< setw(25)
            << this->V.at(i).an << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Dimensiunea tabelului  n= " << V.size() << endl;

}


{
        file >> value->id;
        file >> value->1;
        file >> value->2;
        file >> value->3;
        file >> value->an;

        this->V.push_back(*value);
    }


    file.close();

}
```

in main

```
int main() {

    table<MOBILE>* file = new table<MOBILE>();
    table<MOBILE>* file1 = new table<MOBILE>();

 file ->print();    
 file1 ->print();
```

This is full code as requested.
Need make it somehow print the data from file1 and file2 .
thx

The problem is idk if called right. Because 
     file ->print();
     file1 ->print();
both print data from the file only
    There are no errors at all

Comment: _but only prints from first file_ : what is the behavior ? Do you have a crash stopping the execution ? I am afraid the title nor the question body say all, nor even enough ...

Comment: What is your question about this code?

Comment: You haven't included the code for `MOBILE`. I find it impossible to believe that this code compiles with error, this code `string 1;` is a compile error. There seem to be other errors as well.

Comment: If you want you code to print file `filetxt` and `file1.txt` Then you need to pass the name of the file to use into the `table` constructor.

Comment: table<MOBILE>* file = new table<MOBILE>();
    table<MOBILE>* file1 = new table<MOBILE>();

should be 

  table<HOUSE>* file = new table<HOUSE>();
    table<HOUSE>* file1 = new table<HOUSE>();

I cant get it to output the content from both files. 

file ->print();    
 file1 ->print();

both output the content from file, while file and file1 have diffrent content

Comment: The code you have posted does not compile, yet you say it does. This should be pasted as one contiguous piece of code. Please see:[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code posted was for informational purpose where the changes/error can be.
John solved my problem. Thx everyone

Answer (score 0):

There's lots and lots wrong with your code. but I'm going to ignore that and just answer what I think is your actual question.

You want two `table` objects, one of which reads from `file.txt` and the other reads from `file1.txt`. To do that you should pass the file name into the `table::table` constructor, so it knows which file to read from. Like this

```
template<class Type>
class table
{
    ...
public:
    table(const char* filename); // constructor takes filename parameter
    ...
};


template<class Type>
table<Type>::table(const char* filename)
{
    ifstream file(filename); // open filename
    if (file.fail())
...


int main() {

    table<MOBILE>* file = new table<MOBILE>("file.txt"); // read from file.txt
    table<MOBILE>* file1 = new table<MOBILE>("file1.txt"); // read from file1.txt

    file ->print();    
    file1 ->print();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. Regarding other warrings, are about templates. I dont worry about them.

Cheers